# Angular does not render Textarea changes after file input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

to start off, I am a total beginner regarding Angular. It just so happened, that I started to launch a project using JHipster which makes use of Angular.

**My situation is as follows:**

I've got a textarea where a user can write in some text. After the user presses a submit bottom at the end of the page the changes in the textarea get saved. That by itself works fine.

I made an attempt to increase the functionality of my mask by adding a `input type = file` in which the user can upload a .txt file of his choice. The text gets then written into the textarea, I use this Javascript to make things happen:

```
 function filechooser(evt) {
        var files =  $('#fileinput').prop('files'); // FileList object
        var reader = new FileReader();

        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            if (f) {
                var name = f.name;
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var txtField = $("#field_content");
                    var txtContents = txtField.val();
                    var contents = e.target.result;


                    txtField.val(txtContents + "<!--" + name + "-->" +
                        "\n" + "<!--" + "generated from import" + "-->" +
                        "\n" + "<!--" + getFormattedDate() + "-->" + "\n" + "\n" +
                        contents);
                }
                reader.readAsText(f);
                //$scope.editForm.content.$setDirty();
                //$scope.ngModel.$render();
            } else {
                alert("Failed to load file");
            }
        }
    }
```

this method does as expected and the text from the user selected file is written whitin the textfield.

```
  <textarea class="form-control topic" name="content" id="field_content" ng-model="vm.topic.content"></textarea>
        <!-- filechooser -->
        <input type="file" id="fileinput"/>
        <button type="button" id="fileinputSubmit" ng-click="vm.filechooser()"> submit </button>
```

**The Problem:**

It seems, that Angular does not detect any changes from my programmatically inserted text. Which means, that my textfield remains ng-pristine, ng-untouched etc. Which further means, that hitting the submit button does not save my changes as Angular didnt detect them from the generated text. If I write the text through my input and additionally do an user input, such as a simple whitespace, the save mechanism works just fine.

How can I tell Angular to render my form or revailidate my textarea ? Help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using `$watch` on your `textarea`. but I prefer to do things in angular way rather than using jquery.

Comment: That is not the *Angular way* to do this kind of things...

Answer (score 1):

As this is Angular, you should NOT (never) put the value of the textfield directly via the DOM api.You should NOT do this:

```
var txtField = $("#field_content");
var txtContents = txtField.val();

txtField.val(txtContents + "<!--" + name + "-->" +
                    "\n" + "<!--" + "generated from import" + "-->" +
                    "\n" + "<!--" + getFormattedDate() + "-->" + "\n" + "\n" +
                    contents);
```

Instead, you should update the value of the correspondent ng-model directive, in this case,vm.topic.content.

You should do

```
vm.topic.content =  txtContents + "<!--" + name + "-->" +
                    "\n" + "<!--" + "generated from import" + "-->" +
                    "\n" + "<!--" + getFormattedDate() + "-->" + "\n" + "\n" +
                    contents
```

I can't see where you init the vm.topic object, neither if you are using the VM syntax (in the code I see you are using the $scope syntax...),in that case you can do

```
    $scope.topic.content =  txtContents + "<!--" + name + "-->" +
                    "\n" + "<!--" + "generated from import" + "-->" +
                    "\n" + "<!--" + getFormattedDate() + "-->" + "\n" + "\n" +
                    contents
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: It helped indeed, thanks a lot. But there is one issue left. I have to click another button for my textfield to start to render. I have to render my textfield procrammatically. If i hit the submit button now he does nothing unless I press another button in my mask.